# Best incremental load method using SSIS with over 20 million records

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

**What is needed**: I'm needing 25 million records from oracle incrementally loaded to SQL Server 2012. It will need to have an UPDATE, DELETE, NEW RECORDS feature in the package. The oracle data source is always changing.

**What I have:** I've done this many times before but not anything past 10 million records.First I have an [Execute SQL Task] that is set to grab the result set of the [Max Modified Date]. I then have a query that only pulls data from the [ORACLE SOURCE] > [Max Modified Date] and have that lookup against my destination table.

I have the the [ORACLE Source] connecting to the [Lookup-Destination table], the lookup is set to NO CACHE mode, I get errors if I use partial or full cache mode because I assume the [ORACLE Source] is always changing. The [Lookup] then connects to a [Conditional Split] where I would input an expression like the one below.

```
(REPLACENULL(ORACLE.ID,"") != REPLACENULL(Lookup.ID,"")) 
|| (REPLACENULL(ORACLE.CASE_NUMBER,"") 
!= REPLACENULL(ORACLE.CASE_NUMBER,""))
```

I would then have the rows that the [Conditional Split] outputs into a staging table. I then add a [Execute SQL Task] and perform an UPDATE to the DESTINATION-TABLE with the query below:

```
 UPDATE Destination
 SET SD.CASE_NUMBER =UP.CASE_NUMBER,
     SD.ID           =   UP.ID,
 From Destination SD
 JOIN  STAGING.TABLE UP
    ON UP.ID = SD.ID
```

**Problem:** This becomes very slow and takes a very long time and it just keeps running. How can I improve the time and get it to work? Should I use a cache transformation? Should I use a merge statement instead?

How would I use the expression REPLACENULL in the conditional split when it is a data column? would I use something like :

```
(REPLACENULL(ORACLE.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,"01-01-1900 00:00:00.000") 
 != REPLACENULL(Lookup.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE," 01-01-1900 00:00:00.000"))
```

PICTURES BELOW:

[image: Date Flow]

[image: Control flow]

Comment: The issue is that in your first screenshot, your update tasks (and possibly lookups) are doing RBAR operations. I still don't get how everyone recommends this approach. I can see that your second screenshot uses a better pattern pattern - load into staging and do a bulk update. I suggest you use this same pattern in the prior screenshot - load your oracle data into staging and identify new and updated records with a _single_ update statement.. unless I misunderstand the data flow here. Can you confirm for example that the UPDATE AND NO MATCHED RECORDS step takes the longest in this package.

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE AND NO MATCHED RECORDS are taking the longest, so long that it runs forever. It is mainly the Lookup Transformation that is killing it. When I set it to Full Cache, it extremely hinders my whole laptop. When I set it to partial, it is better but it just runs forever.

Comment: I only lookup reference two columns which I wrote out in a query instead of selecting the table from the drop down. I think I might just have the whole process TRUNCATE and LOAD. I was able to tune the buffer size and have it load in 20 mins , so I might just go with that unless you have any advice and tips for me?

Comment: My advice is: if the datasets you are doing lookups between are on the same SQL server, use a SQL SELECT and JOIN statement to do it. If the dataset and the update target are on the same server use a staging table and an UPDATE statement to do it. You'll see a huge improvement in performance. You can test this by adding and removing components and seeing how fast your package runs. Lookup and Update targets are both partially blocking components

Comment: I'll post a more specific suggestion below

Comment: As mentioned always do the matching logic off the production system.  I have one table with ~45 million rows and I currently drop and reload, then merge but I am not happy with the performance.  I am working on a solution using ORA_ROWSCN and primary keys to try and minimise the workload as much as possible - Basic overview is each ETL should save (not query) the last ROWSCN taken, next load takes ROWSCN and Primary Keys into staging, then from there i grab the full rows and handle accordingly with Merge statements.  Will post if it's a success!

Answer (score 6):

A pattern that is usually faster for larger datasets is to load the source data into a local staging table then use a query like below to identify the new records:

```
SELECT column1,column 2
FROM StagingTable SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TargetTable TGT 
    WHERE TGT.MatchKey = SRC.MatchKey
)
```

Then you just feed that dataset into an insert:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (column1,column 2)
SELECT column1,column 2
FROM StagingTable SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TargetTable TGT 
    WHERE TGT.MatchKey = SRC.MatchKey
)
```

Updates look like this:

```
UPDATE TGT
SET 
column1 = SRC.column1,
column2 = SRC.column2,
DTUpdated=GETDATE()
FROM TargetTable TGT
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TargetTable SRC
    WHERE TGT.MatchKey = SRC.MatchKey
)
```

Note the additional column `DTUpdated`. You should always have a 'last updated' column in your table to help with auditing and debugging.

This is an INSERT/UPDATE approach. There are other data load approaches such as windowing (pick a trailing window of data to be fully deleted and reloaded) but the approach depends on how your system works and whether you can make assumptions about data (i.e. posted data in the source will never be changed)

You can squash the seperate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements into a single `MERGE` statement, although it gets pretty huge, and I've had performance issues with it and there are other documented issues with `MERGE`

Comment: How would you handle the updates? Will you just delete the older columns after the new insert?

Comment: Very nice, let me try this out. Thank you!!

Comment: Added some info about Update

Comment: That's update query is very nice and efficient. Do you think we can use a JOIN instead of a WHERE EXISTS? Exact same query but instead of using a sub query, you use a JOIN and join on the MatchKey

Comment: Yes you can and in all likelihood you'll get an identical query plan. Once upon a time `EXISTS` was in some cases more efficient but nowadays the query planner is smart enough to pick an efficient plan. By all means please try it and let me know if it uses the same query plan or not (CTRL-L)

Comment: Also if you have some metrics to compare the two methods (i.e. how long each method takes), please by all means post them.

Comment: I have tried both and only the join works. Seems as though the WHERE EXISTS sub query does not allow the table in the inner query to be used in the outer query. Take your UPDATE query for example, the Table SRC can not be used in the outer update statement [column1 - src.column1]. I have tried it without using an alias [SRC] and just inputting the actual table name with and without the schema and it doesnt work for me. Error I receive is "The multi-part identifier cannot be bound".

Comment: Though using the JOIN is pretty quick. Using the join method, the package was able to complete in 5 minutes BUT, that is pulling a records from the OLTP based on the MAX MODIFIED DATE minus 2 days, meaning if my last incremental load to our OLAP was on 5/10/2016, the packge will only pull records OLTP records that was past 5/08/2016 and beyond and load them into our OLAP. Either way, this is fairly quick and I was able to get rid of the LOOKUP and CONDITIONAL SPLIT tranformations , saving a ton of time.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It would be interesting to know how long the SSIS lookup/update takes - metrics are good!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not a good way to do what you're trying to do. SSIS has some controls and documented ways to do this, but as you have found they don't work as well when you start dealing with large amounts of data.

At a previous job, we had something similar that we needed to do. We needed to update medical claims from a source system to another system, similar to your setup. For a very long time, we just truncated everything in the destination and rebuilt every night. I think we were doing this daily with more than 25M rows. If you're able to transfer all the rows from Oracle to SQL in a decent amount of time, then truncating and reloading may be an option.

We eventually had to get away from this as our volumes grew, however. We tried to do something along the lines of what you're attempting, but never got anything we were satisfied with. We ended up with a sort of non-conventional process. First, each medical claim had a unique numeric identifier. Second, whenever the medical claim was updated in the source system, there was an incremental ID on the individual claim that was also incremented.

Step one of our process was to bring over any new medical claims, or claims that had changed. We could determine this quite easily, since the unique ID and the "change ID" column were both indexed in source and destination. These records would be inserted directly into the destination table. The second step was our "deletes", which we handled with a logical flag on the records. For actual deletes, where records existed in destination but were no longer in source, I believe it was actually fastest to do this by selecting the `DISTINCT` claim numbers from the source system and placing them in a temporary table on the SQL side. Then, we simply did a `LEFT JOIN` update to set the missing claims to logically deleted. We did something similar with our updates: if a newer version of the claim was brought over by our original Lookup, we would logically delete the old one. Every so often we would clean up the logical deletes and actually delete them, but since the logical delete indicator was indexed, this didn't need to be done too frequently. We never saw much of a performance hit, even when the logically deleted records numbered in the tens of millions.

This process was always evolving as our server loads and data source volumes changed, and I suspect the same may be true for your process. Because every system and setup is different, some of the things that worked well for us may not work for you, and vice versa. I know our data center was relatively good and we were on some stupid fast flash storage, so truncating and reloading worked for us for a very, very long time. This may not be true on conventional storage, where your data interconnects are not as fast, or where your servers are not colocated.

When designing your process, keep in mind that deletes are one of the more expensive operations you can perform, followed by updates and by non-bulk inserts, respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. Quick question,

Comment: When you say "We did something similar with our updates: if a newer version of the claim was brought over by our original Lookup, we would logically delete the old one. Every so often we would clean up the logical deletes and actually delete them, but since the logical delete indicator was indexed, this didn't need to be done too frequently"                       Why didnt you perform an update but decided to just delete the older row and insert the new one? Was this performance faster for you?

Answer (score 1):

[image][image] ****Incremental Approach using SSIS****

1. Get Max(ID) and Max(ModifiedDate) from Destination Table and Store them in a Variables
2. Create a temporary staging table using EXECUTE SQL TASK and store that temporary staging table name into the  variable
3. Take a Data Flow Task and Use OLEDB Source and OLEDB Destination to pull the data from the Source System and load the
   data into the variable of temporary tables
4. Take Two Execute SQL Task one for Insert Process and other for Update
5. Drop the Temporary Table

   INSERT INTO sales.salesorderdetails
   (
   salesorderid,
   salesorderdetailid,
   carriertrackingnumber ,
   orderqty,
   productid,
   specialofferid,
   unitprice,
   unitpricediscount,
   linetotal ,
   rowguid,
   modifieddate
   )
   SELECT    sd.salesorderid,
   sd.salesorderdetailid,
   sd.carriertrackingnumber,
   sd.orderqty,
   sd.productid ,
   sd.specialofferid ,
   sd.unitprice,
   sd.unitpricediscount,
   sd.linetotal,
   sd.rowguid,
   sd.modifieddate
   FROM      ##salesdetails          AS sd WITH (nolock)
   LEFT JOIN sales.salesorderdetails AS sa WITH (nolock)
   ON        sa.salesorderdetailid = sd.salesorderdetailid
   WHERE     NOT EXISTS
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   sales.salesorderdetails sa
   WHERE  sa.salesorderdetailid = sd.salesorderdetailid)
   AND       sa.salesorderdetailid > ?

   UPDATE sa
   SET    SalesOrderID = sd.salesorderid,
   CarrierTrackingNumber = sd.carriertrackingnumber,
   OrderQty = sd.orderqty,
   ProductID = sd.productid,
   SpecialOfferID = sd.specialofferid,
   UnitPrice = sd.unitprice,
   UnitPriceDiscount = sd.unitpricediscount,
   LineTotal = sd.linetotal,
   rowguid = sd.rowguid,
   ModifiedDate = sd.modifieddate
   FROM   sales.salesorderdetails sa
   LEFT JOIN ##salesdetails sd
   ON sd.salesorderdetailid = sa.salesorderdetailid
   WHERE  sa.modifieddate > sd.modifieddate
   AND sa.salesorderdetailid < ?

**Entire Process took 2 Minutes to Complete**

[Incremental Process Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9jOc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have some identity like (pk)column in your oracle table.

1 Get max identity (Business key) from Destination database (SQL server one)

2 Create two data flow

a) Pull only data >max identity from oracle and  put them Destination directly .( As these are new record).

b) Get all record < max identity and update date > last load put them into temp (staging ) table (as this is updated data)

3 Update Destination table with record from temp table record (created at step b)

Comment: Just a quick comment that... don't assume that greater value the identity column will always = columns created later; it is usually the case but not always the case. also, it doesn't take care of records that change over time.

Comment: @TheLyrist it would be great if you can tell the scenario when this condition would not hold it will be learning  .

Comment: The only thing you should trust would be the timestamp (if they are accurate); I won't assume the identity column will always be sequential or in order, as there are times you might not have control over how the identity column is generated (identity insert, or sequence generator, for instance) and the timestamp by itself should let you know what rows might have changed (inserted or updated) and the existence of ID should let you know if it should be updated or inserted. A MERGE statement should be able to help process the UPSERT operation in a single go as needed.